# How does scoring work in Unidentified Falling Objects?

Tags: unidentified-falling-objects

In Unidentified Falling Objects there are objectives to earn a certain amount of points in a single combo. The amount of points you earn seems to be affected by how many blocks you break at once and your current level, but it can be hard to predict how many points a combo will give.

How does combo scoring work? How much of an impact does your level have on the amount of points earned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points are calculated as the number of blocks broken in a single combo squared (including obstacles and powerup boxes), times your current level, times a score modifier if you are playing on hard mode (1.2), rounded to the nearest whole number.

```
Points = blocks broken^2 * level * score modifier
```

For example: A 14-block combo at level 3 on normal mode is worth 588 points (14^2 * 3). The same combo on hard mode is worth 706 points (14^2 * 4 * 1.2).

Below is a table of how many points you will get for combos up to 35 blocks on level 10 or below in normal mode.

[image: Normal mode scores]

Source: I figured out the formula myself by making [a spreadsheet of combos in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SjsURWHn1eafL3CHKuCuZsNYv0rapxNHjvBJP91IgAg/edit?usp=sharing) and analyzing the data. I then checked [a high score video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjDwOosnsHk) to verify the formula worked for higher levels.

[image: List of data around combo points]